# Edit mode, how to toggle between states

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am following this guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-todo-editing-state/

So I wrote this code:

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  headerTitle: 'Editing post'
  buttonTitle: 'Edit'

  destroy: ->
    @content.deleteRecord()
    @store.commit()
    @transitionToRoute('posts')

  save: ->
    @content.save().then =>
      @transitionToRoute('post', @content)

  cancel: ->
    console.log("Canceling! " + @content)
    if @content.isDirty
      @content.rollback()
    @transitionToRoute('post', @content)
```

Post controller:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  commentsVis: false
  isEditing: false

  showComments: () ->
    this.set("commentsVis", true)
    @transitionToRoute('comments', post)

  editMode: ->
    this.set("isEditing", true)
    @transitionToRoute('post.edit')
```

Routes

```
EmberJs.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Post.find(params.post_id)
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
    controller.set('isEditing', false)

EmberJs.PostEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Post.find(params.post_id)
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
```

Views:

Post:

```
<h1>{{title}} / {{parseDate created}} by {{user.email}}</h1>

<p>{{body}}</p>

<div id="discussion">
{{#unless commentsVis}}
<a href="#" {{action 'showComments' this}}>View discussion</a>
{{/unless}}
</div>

{{outlet}}

{{#unless isEditing}}
<button type="submit" {{action 'editMode'}}>
    Edit
</button>
{{/unless}}
```

Edit:

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>

<form>
  <div class="input string">
    <label>Title</label>
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='title' name='title' viewName='titleField'}}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button" {{action save}}>
    Edit
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="button alert" {{action destroy}}>
    Delete
  </button>
<a href="#" {{action cancel}}>Cancel</a>
</form>

{{outlet}}
```

**I have two issues:**

1. When I click cancel, the right template is being loaded, isEditing is changed to false but still the Edit button is hidden.
2. The line @transitionToRoute('post', @content) moves me to an undefined page, seems like @content isn't a model, but a DS.RecordArray. Yesterday it worked fine but seems like some other changes broke it.

Thanks in advance, BBLN!

Comment: you have two different namespaces, `App` & `EmberJs` is this intentional?

Comment: Looks like I didn't replace it on post routes (rails generator sets app name as namespace), anyhow they are both the same, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you post your router code, or better yet make a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BBLN/WRpkb/ I will upload my whole project to github later.

Comment: Is that CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks everybody.

New route:

```
App.PostEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  needs: ['post']
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    this.controllerFor("post").set("isEditing", true)
    controller.set('content', this.controllerFor("post").get("content"))
```

Now having trouble with mongoid :O ([undefined method `first` on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678126/undefined-method-first-on-create) if someone want to help :D)